# Is there any way to differentiate such function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, derivatives

Let $S$ be a set.

If I had a bijection $f$ mapping each element $n\in \mathbb{N}$ to an element $s \in S$ such that:

$$s = f(n) = \sum^{n}_{k=1} {1\over k}$$

Is the function differentiable in respect to $n$?

I know it's an odd question, but it's stuck in my head.

Comment: To differentiate in the usual sense, you need a real or complex variable. (Or more generally a  real or complex vector space.) There are concepts of discrete derivative, though.  What do you need it for.  What is $S$?  It seems $S=\mathbb Q$ or a superset thereof.

Comment: Yes and no. To define differentiation, you need at least to define a metric topology, such that $\forall_\delta\exists_\epsilon ... A<B$ makes some sense.

Comment: Not as stated but you may rewrite $\;f(n)=H_n=\psi(n+1)+\gamma\;$ with $\gamma$ the [Euler constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Euler–Mascheroni_constant) and $\psi$ the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Relation_to_harmonic_numbers). $\psi$ is defined in the whole complex plane (minus the negative integers) and $f(n)$ may even be given as a [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Taylor_series) with $\zeta(k+1)$ coefficients.

Comment: What you are calling a function is really what one would normally call a sequence, that is the function $f$ is actually the sequence $(a_n): \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $a_n = \sum^n_{k = 1} \frac{1}{k}$

Comment: @RaymondManzoni - You Sir...are why Mathematicians are awesome :). Thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped @Max Echendu.

Comment: See [Harmonic Number: Calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation).

Comment: @StellaBiderman Ahh yeah my bad. Been really busy.

Comment: @MaxEchendu no big deal. I'm just obsessive about categorization :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculus is normally done with functions from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. So no, you can't use the derivative you're familiar with on $f$. I can tell you that just by knowing the domain and the codomain (range), without even looking at how your function is defined.

You can see why this doesn't work by looking at the definition of the derivative:

$$f'(x) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}$$

The limit tells us that $h$ is going to get very small. But if your function $f$ is only defined on natural numbers, how do you compute $f(x + .001)$?

Here's something we can do for functions from $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \text{something}$. I feel it preserves many of the main ideas of the derivative. Define $\Delta f(x)$ by:

$$\Delta f(x) = \frac{f(x + 1) - f(x)}{1} = f(x + 1) - f(x)$$

This is just the previous formula with $h = 1$ and without the limit. It's known as the "discrete derivative" or "forward difference" (backward difference would be $f(x) - f(x-1)$). Using it, we can take derivative of sequences: for example, if $f(n) = n^2$, then

$$\Delta f(n) = (n+1)^2 - n^2 = n^2 + 2n + 1 - n^2 = 2n + 1$$

That's showing that the distance between any two square numbers is always odd.

So we can take the discrete derivative of your function:

$$\Delta f(n) = f(n+1) - f(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k} - \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} = \frac{1}{n+1}$$

Comment: Oooohhh the "discrete derivitive"...I like that. I also tried using the definition of a derivitive and too spotted the problem. But I wanted to know if there was another way haha. But I like this "discrete derivitive. I'll read up on it, thank you :).

Comment: @MaxEchendu: I'm glad! I added in the actual discrete derivative of your function. One really nice thing is that discrete integration is just summation. Woop! If you're reading up on this stuff, I found https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/dgleich/publications/Gleich%202005%20-%20finite%20calculus.pdf to be very well written when I was learning about it a while ago.

Comment: Question for experts: can $\text{something}$ be any field?

Answer (score 2):

No. Differentiability is only defined within a certain subset of functions, specifically ones where you can reasonably compute limits. What "reasonably" means depends a bit on the context, but usually requires that it be defined on a field (generally a real field), which $\mathbb{N}$ is not. There are ways to extend the notion of a limit to such places, with ultra filters, but such discussion is not contained within what is normally meant by "derivative" and "limit", so if you're interested in those kinds of behaviors I would recommend you ask specifically about if ultra filters can be used to define a notion of a derivative on discrete sets.